# Two test folders, .NET 2.0 and .NET 6.0

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I wrote tests logging.Tests, but two test files have come up in testExplorer . look at the image below.
.net 2.0 tests will not run. .net 6.0 tests pass without any issues. But this causing problem with coverage, eventhough i have return tests that cover logging(The tests pass too), coverage tool shows less coverage.

[image: 1]

I dont know what to try. I am writing unit tests. But cant increase coverage

Comment: Check the target frameworks of both projects.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "will not run"? What happens when you try? If you right-click on the netstandard 2.0 part of your screenshot (which is quite different from .NET 2.0 by the way), what happens? Normally test projects don't target .NET Standard, but "application" TFMs - perhaps you should target .NET Core 3.1 instead?